# Discrimination based on race and gender

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a *ism* word or similar sounding word e.g. racism, sexism, anti-antisemitism, homophobism/homophobic that I can use to describe in general term discriminatory behavior.
I also require for the same word the form of that word to describe the person e.g. racist, sexist, homophobe, anti-semite

> John asked Sally to please step aside so he can pass. She replied. "No, you're an entitled white male". John responded saying "By generalizing without having ever met me, and classifying me with my sex and race instead of who I am, you are a committing [...ism] or being a [...ist]

I can use discrimination and discriminator/hypocrite but it doesn't sound right as discrimination is so broad and she is using a combination of race and gender. I feel a word ending with ism/ist/ic word would be more applicable.

Comment: Probably answers will not differ widely from those at [Does racism include both race and gender or just race](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/319611/does-racism-include-both-race-and-gender-or-just-race/319644#319644), where **bigotry** seems the best on offer.

Comment: You could describe such a person as *prejudiced* It doesn't end in *...ism*, but does that matter? In most western countries there is no general law of discrimination. As long as one doesn't prefer people according to race, gender, sexual or transgendered orientation, physical disability, age etc, you can discriminate as much as you like. Many people, especially women, suffer discrimination according to their looks, weight, hair-colour and a multitude of other factors. People who indulge in this may be said to be "prejudiced".

Comment: As the others stated, I think the best suggestions for your sentence are "discriminatory/prejudiced" and "bigot"

Comment: Prejudiced and bigoted are good but bigoted seems a bit strong for the context.

Comment: @Hank give prejudiced as the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps **Prejudiced** will fit your situation:

> #### Prejudiced
>
> - Resulting from or having a prejudice or bias for or especially against

([MWD](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/prejudiced))